# Migrate SSHD sftp Logging

Tags: sftp, sshd, oracle-linux

currently my messages log file is filling up with

```
Dec 19 08:46:43 XXXXXXXXX sftp-server[32357]: closedir
```

and similar messages - is there a setting that I can move all sftp-server messages off to another log that can be better managed?

Answer (score 0):

The default logging of all ssh/sftp is to syslog `AUTH` facility

edit `/etc/openssh/sshd_config`
change `Subsystem internal-sftp -l INFO` to

```
Subsystem internal-sftp -l INFO -f LOCAL3
```

where LOCAL3 is a facility not used by any applications in your system. You can choose any `LOCAL0`  to `LOCAL7` instead of `LOCAL3`

then open your syslog or rsyslog config and add the below

```
local3.*                                              /var/log/sftp.log
```

reload syslog and sftp server and you should see all sftp logs go to `/var/log/sftp.log`

You could also send all SSH/SFTP logs to a log file by changing the default facility in `sshd_config`

```
SyslogFacility LOCAL3
```